# Django: Accessing RIght-Hand Info From Left Joins

Tags: django, left-join

I'm doing a complex LEFT JOIN queries, but I'm not sure how to extract information from the joined tables. I see scads of examples that use LEFT JOIN to filter results, but I don't see anyone accessing any of the row values from the LEFT JOIN. First, let's start with a few simplified sample models as an example:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data = models.TextField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'bar'

class FooBar(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foobars')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data = models.TextField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'foobar'

class FuBar(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fubars')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data = models.TextField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fubar'
```

The `Bar` table has a one-to-many relationship to both the `FooBar` and `FuBar` tables. This also means that the `FooBar` and `FuBar` have an implicit many-to-many relationship.

Here's the RAW equivalent of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT
    foobar.id,
    foobar.status,
    foobar.data,
    bar.id,
    bar.status,
    bar.data,
    fubar.id,
    fubar.status,
    fubar.data
FROM foobar
JOIN bar ON bar.id = foobar.bar_id
LEFT JOIN fubar ON fubar.bar_id = bar.id
WHERE
    foobar.status = 1
    AND bar.status = 1
    AND fubar.status = 1;
```

As I look at each entry in the tabular result set, I have all of the information to identify the singular FooBar, Bar, and Fubar records associated with each row and all of their column values. Let's assume that I need to be able to access every single one of these columns in the result-set once the query is completed.

I can reproduce the same joins in Django:

```
q = (FooBar.objects
     .filter(status=1,
             bar__status=1,
             bar__fubars__status=1)
     .select_related('bar'))
```

If I iterate through the result set, I can access the FooBar, and Bar objects without needing to perform any additional queries implicitly or explicitly. The following code snippet illustrates how I can access their information.

```
for fb in q:
    foobar = fb
    foobar_id = fb.id
    foobar_status = fb.status
    foobar_data = fb.data
    bar = foobar.bar
    bar_id = fb.bar.id
    bar_status = fb.bar.status
    bar_data = fb.bar.data

    fubar = ???
    fubar_id = ???
    fubar_status = ???
    fubar_data = ???
```

How can I access the individual FuBar object associated with each iteration? Ideally I'd like to be able to get it without performing any additional queries in the background if possible.

Thanks in advance.

--- edit ---

I have updated the description of the problem above to be a little more clear about the exact nature of the problem. I am looking specifically for the single, specific `FuBar` record associated with each row of the result set. Notice that the following:

`foobar.bar.fubars`

Is not what I want. In short, this returns a set of `FuBar` records related to the `Bar` record in the current result-set's row. It does not tell me which specific record was LEFT JOIN'd to the current row in the result-set.

Comment: Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right/left [sic] table column to be not NULL after a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS Constraints are not needed to query. Tables represent relationships.

Comment: You still aren't clear about what you see as a problem or what your question is. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now. Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear. PS Each result row is a left table row paired with a right table row or a row of NULLs. SQL uses alias.column to refer to a result row column. What are you trying to say?

Comment: The rows in the left join (although you "turn that left join into an inner join") are rows from the first (inner) join left joined to fubar. Are you trying to ask for an expression that you can use to denote the fubar object from which a result row came? A row's non-null fubar.id the id of the object you want. What else do you want? Whatever columns/fields you want from it, put them in the select. Read about column aliases. (If you actually need a left join, for also getting unmatched foobar-bar row pairs, which is not what you get now, of course there is no fubar object for a null fubar.id.)

Comment: Perhaps it's clearer to think of it this way: Here are some example models. Here is a RAW SQL query that I want to perform on them. These are the fields I need to be able to access in the result-set (everything in the SELECT clause). How do I do this using Django's ORM? Is there something else that will make it clearer?

Comment: The query you say you want is the same as if you replaced LEFT by INNER. Do you know that? Is it still what you want? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular base table initialization.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't getting it in without extra queries, but I believe is at least getting you the expected results. As I'm dipping in and out while working on work projects, my brain may not be properly focused. But the idea was to annotate in the FuBar id from the matching Bar of the FooBar row, then do a get on it while iterating (which of course is where the extra queries are from).

I can keep plugging away to see if anything else comes to mind.

```
foobars = FooBar.objects.filter(status=1, bar__status=1, bar__fubars__status=1)
fubar = FuBar.objects.filter(bar=OuterRef('bar')).values('id')
foobars = foobars.annotate(fubar_id=Subquery(fubar[:1]))
foobars = foobars.select_related('bar')

for foobar in foobars:
    bar = foobar.bar

    fubar = bar.fubars.filter(id=foobar.fubar_id).get()
```

Comment: Because this is a LEFT JOIN, what if there are multiple rows joining multiple `FuBar` records with the same `FooBar` record? If I add the `.prefetch_related('bar__fubars')`, and then reference `foobar.bar.fubars`, I will end up with every `FuBar` record that is related to the given `Bar` record for that row, even if they have already been filtered out by the query. How do I access the specific `FuBar` record referenced by that specific row in the result-set?

Comment: Ah, I think I see. A custom Prefetch queryset would be needed:

`.prefetch_related(Prefetch('bar__fubars', queryset=FuBar.objects.filter(status=1))`

I did a pretty minimal POC and believe it works as you intend.

Comment: Closer, but still not what I want. It might be simpler for me to say that I'm looking for a specific `FuBar` record per row, not a set of them. It is still the case that there might be multiple related `FuBar` records where `status=1`. I still don't know which one specifically was joined to that particular row in the result set. I'll try to update the question with a better example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think you understand the question now. I'd have to play with this to see if it gave me the correct results, but I can at least see what you're trying to do. It seems that you should not have to introduce subqueries to do this. Is there something similar to annotate that doesn't require an additional subquery?